# not able to update sqlite3 database from PHP page

Tags: php, sqlite

I have installed PAW server in my android board. In PAW server I have added plug-in PHP. from there I am able to open my all php pages.

BUT the problem is I am not able to do INSERT and UPDATE query to my SQlite3 database.

Do not know what is wrong with that..

Anybody can please help me out.

Comment: You say you can open all your pages, does that also mean that SELECT queries work or is that also a problem?

Comment: Yeap SELECT queries are working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [phpLiteAdmin](http://code.google.com/p/phpliteadmin/) together with PAW on a daily basis.
So you can try to install phpLiteAdmin just to check if your setup is working.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the folder where the SQLite3 database was placed as well as the file have [write permissions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php#57356). Your `SELECT` statement will work fine but `INSERT` and `UPDATE` cannot write to the database.

I also found a link of how you can install/verify the PAW PHP runtime: http://fun2code-blog.blogspot.com/2012/03/paw-runtime-php.html.

Also, have a look at this post I found explaining step by step how to run sqlite from your phone using the correct permissions: http://code.google.com/p/phpliteadmin/issues/detail?id=66

Comment: thank you JLC007 for you help. 
I am not using PAW Runtime, I am using PAW server .
But still I downloaded and installed PAW Runtime but it is not working on  system.
I have given all read-write access to my database.
Any thing else I need to do to make INSERT and UPDATE quires to work?